# Dynamically change source of ng-model

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, binding

I have shipping and billing fields.  If a customer checks a box for "use shipping for billing", I want the billing fields to match the shipping fields.  I could copy over the values, but I would rather re-bind the billing fields to match the shipping ones so if the box is checked and a change is made to shipping, the billing will also update.  So how would I re-bind the source of ng-model or what idiom could I use to bind the billing address fields to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maintain two objects

```
$scope.shipping = { .... };
$scope.billing = { .... };
```

If someone selects that they want to match, just do

```
$scope.billing = $scope.shipping.
```

Since objects are by reference, as they update one the other will also update. You can remove the reference by changing $scope.billing back to whatever you initialized it with:

```
$scope.billing = { .... };
```

If you have a checkbox that you want to bind this too, wire up a data-ng-change on it

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="MY_MODEL" data-ng-change="myFunction() "/>
```

Then in your controller have

```
$scope.MY_MODEL = false;
$scope.myFunction(){
    console.log($scope.MY_MODEL);
}
```

Or don't bind data-ng-change and just $watch the MY_MODEL:

```
$scope.MY_MODEL = false;
$scope.$watch("MY_MODEL", function(){
    console.log($scope.MY_MODEL);
}, true);
```

Comment: Ok nice, that works!  What would be the best way to bind/reset based on if the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: Ok that is almost working but for some reason the data binding on the checkbox isn't updating.  If i set MY_MODEL to true, it is initially checked but when I uncheck it, myFunction() logs it as true still.  Vice versa if it is initially false.  Does the change event intercept data binding?

Comment: Using $scope.$watch on MY_MODEL doesn't fire the callback when the checkbox is clicked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642371/checkbox-not-binding-to-scope-in-angularjs

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-checked` instead of using scope watch to make it light weighted. Don't reinvent the wheel.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="flip" ng-checked="checked();">

$scope.checked = function(){
    if($scope.flip){
        $scope.data = ...  //update the data source            
    }else{
        $scope.data = ...  //update the data source
    } 
}
```

Comment: This would probably also work except that for some reason my checkbox isn't binding to the model properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642371/checkbox-not-binding-to-scope-in-angularjs