# angular checkbox using ng-click to reset the ng-model that is binded to the checkbox, thus prevent the checkbox from being unchecked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I have some logic that on certain senario, I want the first check box to be alway checked. So if user tries to uncheck it, I want to use ng-click to change the ng-model binded to the checkbox to 'true'. But the checkbox is still being unchecked....

How do I achieve keep the checkbox remains checked based on the ng-model's value, without using something like angular.element(elem).attr("checked", true)

```
<input type = 'checkbox' ng-model = 'checkboxValue' ng-click = "handler"/>
```

in the controller

```
$scope.checkboxValue = false;
$scope.handler = function(){
    $scope.checkboxValue = true;
}
```

I want the checkbox remain checked since the ng-model checkboxValue is true...but apparently I missed something here

Here's the plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/WbjZilFLDfbP3mQ4oMgx?p=preview

I stepped into the call stack, looks like I set the ng-model to true, then during $digest, the ng-model is set based on the checkbox's status : checked or unchecked. So it is more like one way binding: bindding the ng-model based on the checkbox status?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642371/checkbox-not-binding-to-scope-in-angularjs#answer-23943930

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5JAVN/1/)

Comment: Update:Oh it just occured to me that is it becuase ng-change happends later than ng-click, it actually fired when the ng-model value changed to true/false after ng-click is fired?
<br/><br/>
Thank you for the answer. I do have a logic in click handler to see if the checkbox state is from check to uncheck, if yes, set the checkboxvalue to true. Why this is not working? ng-change and ng-click both fired every time of clicking...My mind must be short-circled.. ;/

Comment: Though you can do this with ng-change, resetting the value on change is not considered a good User Experience. Ideally, you should disable the check box if it is not allowed to change the value.

Comment: @DarshanJoshi: Thanks for the suggestion. You and the guys below are right, the checkbox should be disabled if it is not allowed to change.

Comment: @snailclimbingtree glad that we could help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to allow users to uncheck the check box, you can use `ng-disabled` directive.

A plunk with fork from your plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2kUYN2F5bZboaPJWMd8?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the info. Most of the time, the checkbox is still checkable. Just in some case prevent user from unchecking it. :)

Comment: Hi,
You can check the updated plunk. ng-disabled can be bound to any angular expression. You can also, bind it to a function. For the cases where you need to prevent user from unchecking, the function can return false.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `ng-change` to call some logic with each change to the checkbox state?

Comment: Thank you for the advice .I will try that. I am not quiet sure why this will help though, cause in the ng-click , I am already checking the state changes....For the checkbox,  doens't click change the checkbox anyway? I mean you click once, the checkbox either change from check to uncheck or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the checkboxValue for changes and then change it however you like rather than hooking in through ng-click. If you wanted behavior where the checkbox is initially false, and then true forever once clicked you could do something like:

```
$scope.checkboxValue = false;
$scope.$watch('checkboxValue', function(newValue, oldValue){
    $scope.checkboxValue = newValue || oldValue;
});
```

Here's the required changes to your plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XPZXSzsnaZDGlIi8mxnM?p=preview