# Checkbox and ng-change. Need to uncheck if condition exists

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to programmatically set a checkbox to unchecked when an event happens (the event is actually a modal being hidden). I need to keep the current `ng-change` function with the same parametes.

I have a checkbox element:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="change(ordered, $index, {{part.id}}, {{part.vehicle_id}}, '{{part.ordered_from}}')" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="ordered" name="part-ordered"  />
```

And my JS:

```
$scope.change = function(value,  part_index, id, vehicle_id, ordered_from_val) {

    if (modal_hidden_event) {

        // UNCHECK CODE.             

    }

}
```

I am not too sure what to search for or what area of the docs will help me.

Comment: all that should be necessary is setting your model to false, i.e. `$scope.ordered = false;`

Comment: No need expression tag ( ***{{ }}*** ) in ng-change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular checkbox using ng-click to reset the ng-model that is binded to the checkbox, thus prevent the checkbox from being unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423893/angular-checkbox-using-ng-click-to-reset-the-ng-model-that-is-binded-to-the-chec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where modal_hidden_event is coming from, I am assuming it is just a placeholder here. I've also cleaned up your change function in the HTML, as it does not need to be interpolated, as the values exist without:

Use [ng-checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox"
    ng-change="change(ordered, $index, part.id, part.vehicle_id, part.ordered_from)"
    ng-true-value="1"
    ng-false-value="0"
    ng-model="ordered"
    ng-checked="checkedStatus"
    name="part-ordered"  />
```

**JS**

```
$scope.checkedStatus = true;
$scope.change = function(value,  part_index, id, vehicle_id, ordered_from_val) {

    if (modal_hidden_event) {
        $scope.checkedStatus = false;
    }

}
```

I also recommend just passing the part into the function, and you can grab each property there:

**HTML**

```
"change(ordered, $index, part)"
```

$scope.change = function(value, part_index, part) {

**JS**

```
$scope.change = function(value, part_index, part) {

    var part_id = part.id,
        vehicle_id = part.vehicle_id,
        ordered_from_val = part.ordered_from;


    if (modal_hidden_event) {
        $scope.checkedStatus = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have also created another question related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678552/need-to-uncheck-checkbox-in-list-if-condition-exists