# angular ng-model is not working for input type=checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

My code is like this:
html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb1"> You have discussed the amount, frequency and term applicable to the payment schedule with your customer and they have agreed.
```

get the checkbox value with

```
console.log('checkbox:', $scope.cb1);
```

the result is always `undefined` regards whether I check the box or not.

But if my code changes to

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb1.value"> You have discussed the amount, frequency and term applicable to the payment schedule with your customer and they have agreed.
```

and initialize the variable:

```
$scope.cb1 = {value: true};
```

then I can get the checkbox value with

```
console.log('checkbox:', $scope.cb1.value);
```

would anybody tell me why? thanks

Comment: `console.log('checkbox:", $scope.cb1);` is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: can you show us the controller code.

Comment: This issue is a known one. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc) and the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642371/checkbox-not-binding-to-scope-in-angularjs)

Comment: @VivekSingh I am building a complex app, so have a heap of code in the controller. But i've already shown all the relevant code

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/5y0jadt0/1/

Answer (score 2):

What worked was to bind the input to an object instead of a primitive.

```
<!-- Partial -->
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="someObject.someProperty"> Check Me!

// Controller
 $scope.someObject.someProperty = false
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the scope in which you have defined the checkbox is different from the scope in which you are doing the console.log.

So the checkbox is updating the model in some other scope. 
And you are logging model from some other scope thus the discrepancy.
In HTML like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox"  ng-change="change()" ng-model="myCheck"> You have discussed the amount, frequency and term applicable to the payment schedule with your customer and they have agreed.
  </div>
```

on JS side:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myCheck = true;
  $scope.change = function() {
    console.log("hello", $scope.myCheck);
  };
}]);
```

See my working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/s2D0TjFvrOFDTryH5IvI?p=preview).

The reason why `$scope.cb1 = {value: true};` is working because now cb1 is an object and when a child scope in which the checkbox is present extends the parent scope. It gets the reference of `$scope.cb1` object (shallow clone). 
So change in child scope (for cb1) reflects in parent scope **also** where you doing `console.log`.

Well, when you use `$scope.cb1 = true` in parent scope. 
The child scope gets a clone of it and so parent and child for the variable will differ.

Hope this clarifies your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having the same code as below?

Controller code:

```
$scope.cb1 = false; // initialise it to `true` if you need
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb1"> You have discussed the amount, frequency and term applicable to the payment schedule with your customer and they have agreed.
{{ cb1 }} <!-- check the value of `$scope.cb1` realtime -->
```

### Edit:

To check the value of `cb1` in browser console, do the following,

HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb1" ng-change="changeCheckbox()"> You have discussed the amount, frequency and term applicable to the payment schedule with your customer and they have agreed.
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.cb1 = false; // initialise it to `true` if you need
$scope.changeCheckbox = function() {
    console.log("checkbox: ", $scope.cb1);
}
```

Comment: I can get correct value if I use {{cb1}}, but cannot get it insider controller

Comment: @BenjaminLi Please check my edited code. It is working perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your logging mechanism:

Try this and tell if the problem is fixed

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb1" ng-change="recordLog()"> You have discussed the amount, frequency and term applicable to the payment schedule with your customer and they have agreed.
```

and in your controller.js

```
$scope.recordLog = function() {
    console.log("checkbox:" + $scope.cb1);
}
```

*P.S.: It's only a wild guess from my side. Actual problem may be somewhat different.*

**EDIT**

and of course there's a problem in your js
use

```
console.log("checkbox:" + $scope.cb1.value);
```

instead of

```
console.log('checkbox:", $scope.cb1.value);
```

Comment: why my console.log is wrong? I can see MDN is using the similar one:var car = "Dodge Charger";
var someObject = {str:"Some text", id:5}; 
console.info("My first car was a", car, ". The object is: ", someObject);https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console

Comment: @BenjaminLi I didn't mean to say that the signature of `console.log` is wrong. Signature is correct, you can pass as many arguments as you want (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) But dont you see that you started the first argument with single inverted comma and ended it with double inverted comma in your code. i.e., `console.log('checkbox:", $scope.cb1.value);`

Comment: get your point. that's typo. in my real code, I don't have this single inverted comma and double inverted comma issue. Sorry for that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement `ng-model` with `<input type='"checkbox"..` is :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
```

Here the `checkboxModel` is a `Json` which is structured like this:

```
 $scope.checkboxModel = {
   value1 : true,
   value2 : 'YES'
 };
```

You will not be able to bind the `checkboxModel` by just writing `ng-model="checkboxModel"`

Answer (score 0):

```
.directive('checkbox', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (element.is('.ui')) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $(element).checkbox();
                    element.find('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
                        var checkbox = angular.element(this);
                        eval('scope.' + checkbox.attr('ng-model') + '=' + checkbox.is(':checked'));
                    });
                }, 0);
            }
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: mention point, what you did.