# Using Angular to post data to Moodle API

Tags: angularjs, json, http, post, moodle

According to the answers to previous questions about [posting data back to a server API with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data), you need to [post the data as a plain-text string instead of as Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However, I am thinking that there is a built-in function within the Moodle library that already deals with Json posted to it, in which case I should just be able to send Json. Is that correct?

And if it *is* correct, should I url-encode my Json string?

This is my function so far, which is inside my controller.

```
myApp.controller('mydataCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
url = concatUrl + 'local_webservice_ws_get_mydata';          // GET
updateUrl = concatUrl + 'local_webservice_ws_set_mydata';    // SET
$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
    $scope.mydata = response.data;
});

$scope.sendmypost = function () {
    // Writing it to the server

    $http.post(updateUrl, $scope.mydata).then(function (response) {
        // Success
        $scope.server_response = [
                    { 'message':'Your settings have been updated' }
            ];
    }, function (response) {
        // Error
        $scope.server_response =  [
                    { 'message':'Unexpected error' }
            ];
      });
   } 
});
```

Comment: Moodle can handle json, but the webservices api typically would require a security token, and the data parameters normally are validated by type (PARAM_INT etc).

Are you creating a module? a theme? The best way to proceed is to copy something that already works and modify that.

Comment: hi @brianlmerritt, I am creating a mobile app which collects data from a webservice. So there aren't any functions in Moodle which do what I want.

Comment: And yes the webservice validates the parameters, and I am using token authentication.

Comment: Cool - so I suggest you clone a copy of the actual moodle mobile app at https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2 and have a look to see how they do it. It's all angular 1.x

Comment: uhhmmm yeah so I had a look and I have no idea what their app is doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a brilliant tutorial which does submit angular data to the server and return a response.

**[$http.post server request in AngularJS](http://techfunda.com/howto/565/http-post-server-request)** 
How to send data to server using HttpPost method in AngularJS

And if you are using a checkbox to change the data on the server, you will need this [Stack Overflow post about how to bind a checkbox to the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642371/checkbox-not-binding-to-scope-in-angularjs). The [answer by zsong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18642450/5264501) worked for me.